# Where is the Keytool application?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-mapview, keytool

I need to use mapview control in android and I can't seem to understand how to run `keytool`.
Is it installed with eclipse? I can't seem to find a download link.

Thanks

Answer (score 209, accepted):

[`keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) is part of the standard java distribution.

In a windows 64-bit machine, you would normally find the jdk at

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin`

It is used for managing keys and certificates you can sign things with, in your case, probably a jar file.

If you provide more details of what you need to do, we could probably give you a more specific answer.

Comment: how can I use it? it is not available from the cmd propmp in windows

Comment: Your link points to the Java 1.3 (very old!) documentation. The docs for the Java SE 6 version are here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

Comment: @Amit if you have the JDK installed and added the `bin` folder of your JDK to the `PATH` you should be able to use the `keytool`.

Comment: Funny, the question is "where", not "what", is keytool... why was this even accepted.

Comment: @Zoomzoom: Thought the same after ending up here. Edited the question to fix this.

Comment: Installing entire JDK is not necessary if you need just keytool. It is sufficient to install JRE (Jave Runtime) - it is smaller than JDK (Java Development Kit)

Answer (score 206):

`keytool` is a tool to manage (public/private) security keys and certificates and store them in a `Java KeyStore` file (stored_file_name.jks).
It is provided with any standard `JDK`/`JRE` distributions.
You can find it under the following folder `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: `$JAVA_HOME/bin` for Linux and friends

Comment: @evandrix When I open keytools.exe it keeps closing.

Comment: It's not meant to be opened, it's a command line tool (and should close as soon as it prints whatever it prints initially).

Comment: Do not forget the double quotes, depending on your (Windows) configuration : `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool"`

Comment: keytool is provided not only in JDK but also in JRE destribution which takes less disk space

Answer (score 12):

For me it turned out to be in c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin (Windows 8). A more general answer to this question is that it will most likely be in the bin sub directory of wherever your jdk is installed.

Answer (score 9):

> keytool it's a binary file into the JDK folder ... just add your JDK
>   as environment variable by adding the following line

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with a Mac... the keytool is part of the Java SDK and can be found in the following location /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/[VERSION].jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool

Answer (score 5):

here: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
it is an exe keytool.exe

Answer (score 4):

It is in path/to/jdk/bin.
Make sure that $JAVA_HOME is defined, and $JAVA_HOME/bin is added to $PATH, or else the 'keytool' command won't be recognized when called.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Android installed in windows, you will also find it here:
C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\jre\bin

Answer (score 2):

If you have java installed of course keytool is in there. What you need to do is to add it on your PATH variable.

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio users

If you have Android installed in windows, you will also find it here:

**C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin**

Add this path in Enviourment variables and save it
After then you can use keytool on your terminal/command prompt