# How do I verify that an Android apk is signed with a release certificate?

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore

How can I check that an Android apk is signed with a release and not debug cert?

Comment: I wrote [a script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnnylambada/robospanner/master/apk/apk-validate) that will validate an apk against a keystore.

Comment: accept answer if you have got yours.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada How can I run your script in Mac?

Comment: @JohnnyLambada How can I run your script?

Comment: @sunil It's a bash script that creates a new bash function. follow the link and paste it into a file then `source thatfile`. Comments in the script explain how to run it.

Comment: @PavelGP 's answer is the best one for dealing with apks. `jarsigner` and `keytool` will sometimes incorrectly report that the apk is `Not a signed jar file` when it's signed with the android debug key, whereas `apksigner` will report the android debug key correctly.

Comment: Nowadays, you *must* use `apksigner` to verify the signature of an APK if you want to be sure that the result is correct.

Starting from Android 7.0, new signature schemes have been introduced that cannot be verified using `keytool`. And as the Android build tools will use these new signature schemes exclusively depending on an app's `minSdk`, `keytool` will show invalid information for such apps.

Answer (score 448):

Use this command, (go to java < jdk < bin path in cmd prompt)

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

If you see "CN=Android Debug", this means the .apk was signed with the debug key generated by the Android SDK
(means it is unsigned), otherwise you will find something for CN.
For more details see: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I got the message as jar verified at the end of the command execution for 2 diff apk files.so got confused. but as it gives CN="android debug" for 1 apk and different for other apk .got to knw which 1 is signed .Thanks .

Comment: @iRunner ALL apps need to be signed before installing on a device, using either debug key or real key.

Comment: How does this verify the signature? Will it use the system's trusted CAs? Or this is only a tool to check the integrity of the jar files? Thank you

Comment: `this means the .apk was signed with the debug key generated by the Android SDK (means it is unsigned)` - this does not means it is unsigned. It means what you just wrote - it is signed with debug key.

Comment: How could we check that it was signed with the same exact certificate file, and not just one that happens to have the same values for organisation, location, etc.. ?

Comment: Thanks. So `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myapp.apk | grep CN= | less` and we should not see "CN=Android Debug".

Comment: hello i got message **jar verified** is signed or not.

Comment: To use something other than the debug keystore, use  `jarsigner -verify -keystore my_prod_keystore.jks -verbose -certs my_application.apk`

Answer (score 149):

Use console command:

`apksigner verify --print-certs application-development-release.apk`

You could find apksigner  in ../sdk/build-tools/24.0.3/apksigner.bat. Only for build tools v. 24.0.3 and higher.

Also read google docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html

Comment: I found `apksigner` in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\` (and every other build tools version I had installed)

Comment: Note that `apksigner` is missing in version `26.0.0` of build-tools. It is tracked in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62696222 and supposed to be fixed in the next version. The workaround until then is to use `apksigner` from `25.0.3`.

Comment: Update: `apksigner` is included in version `26.0.1`

Comment: Update: APKSigner is also in 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.0, 27.0.1, 27.0.2
I believe you will find it in all future releases :)

Comment: for verbose output use -v : `./apksigner verify --print-certs -v  ~/Downloads/MyAppHere.apk`

Comment: This is the best option for apks, as sometimes both the `jarsigner` and `keytool` will incorrectly report that the apk is `Not a signed jar file` but `apksigner` gets it right every time.

Comment: getting error like file not found

Answer (score 85):

The easiest of all:

```bash
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile file.apk
```

This uses the Java built-in keytool app and does not require extraction or any build-tools installation.

Comment: For anyone who can't run `keytool` immediately, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830253/where-is-the-keytool-application) and maybe try adding `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the path

Comment: We can check for the app bundle using the same command.

Comment: You can use only one command at once, `list` or `printcert`.

Answer (score 64):

Use this command : (Jarsigner is in your Java bin folder goto java->jdk->bin path in cmd prompt)

```
$ jarsigner -verify my_signed.apk
```

If the .apk is signed properly, Jarsigner prints "jar verified"

Comment: This is not good enough since both debug and release apks are signed will give "jar verified". Check the details of @Anass's answer.

Comment: I tried exactly this command and it verified. Then as an experiment I went into the APK and deleted literally every file except the sig files and the manifest, and it still verified. So something is very wrong here. However I have yet to try @Anass's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command in Terminal - if you have Android Studio.

```
$ /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -printcert -jarfile example.apk
Not a signed jar file
```

Answer (score 2):

- 1. unzip apk
- 2. `keytool -printcert -file ANDROID_.RSA or keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app.apk` to obtain the hash md5
- `keytool -list -v -keystore clave-release.jks`
- compare the md5

https://www.eovao.com/en/a/signature%20apk%20android/3/how-to-verify-signature-of-.apk-android-archive

Answer (score 2):

**Using `keytool` or `jarsigner` may not work for you.** You need to first understand how signing works. [See here](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning).

**If your min API is lower than 24**, v1 signing will be included in apk (inside `META_INF`). And because of that, these two tools will "poop out" your cert keys.

**If using min API 24 or higher**, v1 signing will be excluded (unless you enable it on your own in `build.gradle`). In this case `keytool` or `jarsigner` don't work. They will output `Not a signed jar file` or `jar is unsigned`. To verify v2+ signature, you should use `apksigner` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```bash
keytool -printcert -jarfile base.apk
```