# Android generate unsigned apk using gradle

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, apk, unsigned

I have an Android Project (with Android Studio and Gradle) and a *Jenkins CI Server* that build this one.

What I'm trying to do is to generate a *completely unsigned certificate*.

In fact, when the server builds the application, it does generate an **-unsigned.apk** but it seems that this *apk* **is** signed by the *developper certificate*.

In fact I checked this out by downloading the apk and running the following command (after reading [How do I verify that an Android apk is signed with a release certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-do-i-verify-that-an-android-apk-is-signed-with-a-release-certificate))

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app-unsigned.apk | grep Android
```

So the output is like

```
X.509, CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
```

(with a lot of rows)

For what it worth, I build the app running the gradle tasks :

```
clean assemble lint
```

And after that, I zipaling all the apks by running

```
zipalign -f -v 4 *.apk
```

My **build.gradle** doesn't contain any signing option

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // proguard
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            // ZipAlign
            zipAlign false
        }

        release {
            // proguard
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            // ZipAlign
            zipAlign true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        // Don't abort if Lint finds an error, otherwise the Jenkins build
        // will be marked as failed, and Jenkins won't analyse the Lint output
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: After some readings it seems that I have to build in release mode to get an unsigned apk that I have to sign by myself ? [Android dev](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#ReleaseMode) `If you build your application unsigned, then you will need to manually sign and align the package.` I'll try that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I managed to get the result.

The fact was in the task I was using for my build.

I used

```
clean assemble lint
```

And then I **changed for**

```
clean assembleRelease lint
```

The generated apk is now *app-release-unsigned.apk* but when I run the command

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app-release-unsigned.apk | grep Android
```

the output is *nothing* so I guess it worked.

This is a mystery for me because I thought `assemble` was a kind of *shortcut* for `assembleDebug` and then `assembleRelease` [like I read on gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) but it seems that the apk generated has the same name (app-release-unsigned.apk) but one of them is signed, the other not.

Anyway, using `assembleRelease` seems to work.