# React Native : package parse error

Tags: android, windows, react-native

when i try to generate a release version using the following command:

> cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

an apk file is generated in the directory:

> /app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk

Unfortunately when i try to install the apk on my phone with Android 5. i got the following error:

> **There was a problem parsing the package.**

[image]

Note that i am using react native under windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am answering on my own question.
The issue has been solved by generating a signing key as mentioned in
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html
.

Comment: How to check if our APK has signing key or not ?

Comment: Please check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-do-i-verify-that-an-android-apk-is-signed-with-a-release-certificate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks @Moussawi7