# How Can We Check the Signature of a Not-Yet-Installed APK?

Tags: android

Given that we have an APK file, accessible on an Android device on the filesystem, how can we, from another Android app:

- Confirm that the APK file has not been tampered with (that its digital signature matches its contents)?
- Get the public key information (specifically, the same sort of SHA256 hash that `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile test.apk` would emit on a development machine)?

Note that this APK has not been installed at this point, so we cannot use `PackageManager` to retrieve the "signatures" of the installed app, nor can we rely on Android having validated the APK signature for us.

Comment: May be the answers over here can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7104624/4350275

Comment: @PrerakSola: That code is for running on a developer machine. It is not for running on Android itself, which is what this question is focused on. Thanks, though!

Comment: You should be able to use [PackageParser.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java) code ...fx: you can read certs like [this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/fe855fb4d12f08a8d6b3becffdc7c458) then compare it with META-INF/CERT.SF

Comment: @Selvin: That has potential. I knew the AOSP had to have code that did this sort of thing, but I wasn't sure where. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally whiffed on this. `PackageManager` has a `getPackageArchiveInfo()` method, available since API Level 1.

So, you call that, passing in the path to the APK, along with `PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES`. If you get `null` back, the APK was tampered with and does not have valid digital signature. If you get a `PackageInfo` back, it will have the "signatures", which you can use for comparison purposes.