# How to verify apk signature from a shell command prompt?

Tags: android, shell, installation

I would like to know how to verify an apk signature (and installer) from a shell command prompt.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I verify that an Android apk is signed with a release certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-do-i-verify-that-an-android-apk-is-signed-with-a-release-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Android documentation, to verify your apk from the shell     `apksigner verify my-app.apk`

[Sign Your App Manually](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually)