# would "Build APK" sign the apk if signingconfig & release mode is defined

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore

*build.gradle:*

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'asdfasdf'
            keyPassword 'asdfs'
            storeFile file('D:/Keystore/sfs.jks')
            storePassword 'fdfd'
        }
    }
...
```

if I misplace file path in storeFile, whild building apk Studio gives `.jks file not found`. It requires signingConfigs.

Just want to quick confirm,
`Build` -> `Build APK(s)` creates signed apk if signingconfig is defined in release mode(i.e. `release` is chosen in `Build Variant`)?

Comment: Whats the problem you face?

Comment: Just want to quick confirm, Build -> Build APK(s) creates signed apk in this case

Comment: Yes, it does if everything is configured correctly.

Comment: could you provide links please

Comment: Ofcourse it will

Comment: Simply try it out. I'll not do your work for you. Sorry dude.

Comment: Tried. It generates apk but how would one know if it's signed or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-do-i-verify-that-an-android-apk-is-signed-with-a-release-certificate

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will create signed apk, for debug apk you need to select Build Variant as debug.

Comment: No it is creating apk with name "app-<flavor>-unsigned"