# How to fix the following issue?

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, publish, developer-console

So I finished my first unity android game. I created the keystore...build it...and my game works just fine. But when I try to upload the apk to Google Developer console, it is showing an upload error - "You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"

Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance.
[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5kWK.png)

Comment: What version of the Android SDK tools are you using? You may want to consider updating if it's an old one.

Comment: @Pierre 27.0.1 is the version

Comment: Did you enter the keystore information in the publishing section of the player settings?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes I did

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-do-i-verify-that-an-android-apk-is-signed-with-a-release-certificate