# APK is not installing .(Error) "The package appears to corrupt". (Unity 3D Game)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity 3D. When I make a signed build and try to install it on a phone it gives me the error `APK not Installed. The package appears to corrupt`.

But when I make an unsigned build everything works fine. 
But I need a signed apk.

My phone does not have already this app installed. My plugin is fully upgraded.

Comment: I would suggest trying to verify that the apk is signed correctly. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-do-i-verify-that-an-android-apk-is-signed-with-a-release-certificate  `aapt`from the Android SDK and `apktool` from https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ may also be helpful.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for your help. i have solved the problem. i simply just change the pc and make build. it solved my issue.