# How to read the signature into ByteArray from an external APK file

Tags: java, android, apk, signature

I was trying to crack an apk file and learn its coding philosophy. Here is a part of its source code, which is decompiled from the apk file:

[image: SOURCE CODE]

For some reason I need the value of this `encodeToString`. And I wonder is there a way to get the `Byte[]` format of the signature from this apk file? Or the raw value is better.

I've try some tools like **jarsigner** from [How do I verify that an Android apk is signed with a release certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-do-i-verify-that-an-android-apk-is-signed-with-a-release-certificate), to print all the signs out. But I'm not sure if there is any different from the original methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a silly question. Just copy the package name of the target app and replace it into `getPackageName()` and everything's fine.