# How to Sign an Already Compiled Apk

Tags: android, android-install-apk, apk

I've decoded an APK with apktool (as the original source code was lost) so I could fix some issues with the layout xml files. I've then rebuilt it back up with apktool and when I tried to install it on my device (using adb: adb install appname.apk) it gave me this error:

```
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

the original apk however was signed by a keystore (on eclipse IDE), this one isn't, how can I sign it properly with it's original keystone file outside Eclipse!?

Comment: yeah, the whole point of certificates is to stop people from doing this...  If you don't have the original cert you are gonna have to regenerate one

Comment: that's just it, i have the original cert, but decoding/re-building the apk removed it.

Comment: Note: All answers to this question that make use of `jarsigner` are outdated. APKs signed by jarsigner will not be accepted by recent Android versions (AFAIR Android 10+). You need to use `apksigner` from Android SDK.

Comment: @Robert I just tested and an APK file signed with jarsigner before zipalign is running on Android 13. Also on https://developer.android.com/tools/zipalign it says jarsigner is not recommended but it is still mentioned as a solution so it should work on recent Android versions.

Comment: @baptx jarsigner is outdated since a lot of years. The only way to correctly sign an APK is `apksigner` from Android SDK. jarsigner is only needed for ancient Android versions before 5 (not 100% sure if it was exactly that version so may be 1 version plus or minus).

Answer (score 385, accepted):

create a key using

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

then sign the apk using :

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

[check here for more info](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#setup)

Comment: if you do this and try to install the APK, you might end up with a INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION error. This happens when the original APK cannot be overwrited (system or built-in app for instance)

Comment: @Couitchy adb shell pm install -r /data/tmp/myapk.apk

Comment: if you dont want to bother creating a key you can use the debug key with: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore app.apk androiddebugkey -storepass android

Comment: Is there a difference between using `jarsigner` and `apksigner`? One requires signing and then zipaligning and the other zipaligning and then signinig

Comment: Debug key lives only 1 year since SDK installation, so it is not a good idea to use it for a release.

Comment: What is the Difference between Jar signer and Apk signer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153144/what-is-the-difference-between-jar-signer-and-apk-signer

Comment: For Windows I couldn't find jarsigner but I did find apksigner.bat in the Android Studio sdk folder, which did work great. ;) Perhaps this is the NEW way? Anyhow, the file was in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\{version}` for Android Studio and also in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\{version}` (or similar path) for Visual Studio 2017 users.

Comment: Would like to nominate this for best answer on Stack overflow

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for how to specify an alias, the documentation was confusing and does not provide clear examples.

Comment: getting Error: `Only one alias can be specified`

Comment: There's the error I'm getting when running `jarsigner`: jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 2025 but got 1897 bytes)

Comment: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore xxxrelease.jks -alias xxxrelease -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` and after run 
`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore xxxrelease.jks OppoSignVerify.apk xxxrelease` works this way for me. I just copied .jsk file from my android project

Answer (score 137):

## Automated Process:

Use this tool (uses the new apksigner from Google):

https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the developer :)</sup>

## Manual Process:

### Step 1: Generate Keystore (only once)

You need to generate a keystore once and use it to sign your `unsigned` apk.
Use the [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) [provided by the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830253/where-is-the-keytool-application) found in `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/`

```bash
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias app
```

### Step 2 or 4: Zipalign

[`zipalign`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html) [which is a tool provided by the Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442213/cannot-find-zip-align-when-publishing-app) found in e.g. `%ANDROID_HOME%/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/` is a mandatory optimization step if you want to upload the apk to the Play Store.

```bash
zipalign -p 4 my.apk my-aligned.apk
```

**Note:** when using the old `jarsigner` you need to zipalign *AFTER* signing. When using the new `apksigner` method you do it *BEFORE* signing (confusing, I know). [Invoking zipalign before apksigner works fine](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html) because apksigner preserves APK alignment and compression (unlike jarsigner).

You can *verify* the alignment with

```bash
zipalign -c 4 my-aligned.apk
```

### Step 3: Sign & Verify

#### Using build-tools 24.0.3 and newer

Android 7.0 introduces APK Signature Scheme v2, a new app-signing scheme that offers faster app install times and more protection against unauthorized alterations to APK files (See [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2) and [here](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2.html) for more details). Therefore, Google implemented their [own apk signer called `apksigner`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) (duh!)
The script file can be found in `%ANDROID_HOME%/sdk/build-tools/24.0.3/` (the .jar is in the `/lib` subfolder). Use it like this

```bash
apksigner sign --ks-key-alias alias_name --ks my.keystore my-app.apk
```

and can be verified with

```bash
apksigner verify my-app.apk
```

[The official documentation can be found here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually)

#### Using build-tools 24.0.2 and older

Use [`jarsigner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) which, like the keytool, [comes with the JDK distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135699/where-is-jarsigner) found in  `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/` and use it like so:

```bash
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my.keystore my-app.apk my_alias_name
```

and can be verified with

```bash
jarsigner -verify -verbose my_application.apk
```

Comment: For build-tools 24.0.3 correct way to call zipalign is:
    zipalign -p 4 my.apk my-aligned.apk

Comment: Thanks for your description! tried uber-apk-signer first but failed probably because I have openJDK installed on my system instead of oracles "official" java. So I tried the manual way and also failed (still same error `[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]`). Verifying with uber-apk-signer gave me some further insight `signature VERIFY FAILED` [...] `ERROR: JAR signer CERT.RSA: JAR signature META-INF/CERT.RSA uses digest algorithm 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 and signature algorithm 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 which is not supported on API Levels [[15, 17]]`. Yes, android 4.2.2, SHA256 not there? ideas?

Comment: @antiplex please report the issue in github not SO

Comment: @for3st do you mean that my issues may not be due to my limited knowledge around apk-signing but due to some form of incompatibility of uber-apk-signer? but even then the manual way also fails which seems unrelated to your tool...

Comment: For those looking for the command line tool location, I found it in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\{version}` for Android Studio and also in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\{version}` (or similar path) for Visual Studio 2017 users.

Comment: `zipalign -p 4 my.apk my-aligned.apk` says `ERROR: unknown flag -p`.

Comment: Seems like `--ks-key-alias` is not needed, if there's only key in a keystore.

Comment: The following command worked for me: `zipalign 4 my.apk my-aligned.apk` (without the `-p` option).

Comment: Did you set up env variable for apksigner? I am getting command not found

Comment: @Patrick, **Thank You!**  Great tool, and great explanations both in this StackOverflow answer and in readme.md on your GitHub repo. After hours of googling and trials and errors, I finally landed here and I was able to re-sign my disassembled/reassembled APK in a few minutes with **uber-apk-signer**!

Answer (score 18):

fastest way is by signing with the debug keystore:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore app.apk androiddebugkey -storepass android
```

or on Windows:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore test.apk androiddebugkey -storepass android
```

Comment: jarsigner is deprecated and should no longer be used. APKs signed by jarsigner will not work on recent Andorid versions.

Answer (score 7):

You use jarsigner to sign APK's. You don't have to sign with the original keystore, just generate a new one. Read up on the details: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: the link has been broken

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who don't want to create a bat file to edit for every project, or dont want to remember all the commands associated with the keytools and jarsigner programs and just want to get it done in one process use this program:

http://lukealderton.com/projects/programs/android-apk-signer-aligner.aspx

I built it because I was fed up with the lengthy process of having to type all the file locations every time.

This program can save your configuration so the next time you start it, you just need to hit Generate an it will handle it for you. That's it.

No install required, it's completely portable and saves its configurations in a CSV in the same folder.

Comment: Does not work for me. No certificate is added to APK. Seems like it does nothing. Do not even ask for an alias password.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer**

Check https://shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/android-apk-signing-tool-apk-signer/

**Old answer**

check [apk-signer](https://bitbucket.org/haibison/apk-signer/) a nice way to sign your app

Comment: most properly because it was an old thread, you can have a look to this one
https://shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/android-apk-signing-tool-apk-signer/

Comment: both links are now deprecated. do not use

Answer (score 0):

For editing package name

```
apktool d "app.apk"
in app\apktool.yml, change renameManifestPackage to "new.package.name"
apktool b "app"
```

For signing

```
@echo off
cd "app\dist"
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias app
del "app2.apk"
%localappdata%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\zipalign.exe -p 4 "app.apk" "app2.apk"

REM Signing the APK
%localappdata%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\apksigner.bat sign --ks my.keystore --ks-key-alias app "app2.apk"

REM Verifying the APK
%localappdata%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\apksigner.bat verify "app2.apk"

adb -s 192.168.1.25:5555 install "app2.apk"
```