# Cannot start "jarsigner.exe" process in Windows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

I am generating a release Android app bundle in Android Studio, but I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start "jarsigner.exe" process, please add it to the PATH

I have installed Java JDK and JRE and I am using Windows. Please see the error details in the screenshot:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: The answer is already in the error message "Cannot start "jarsigner.exe" process, please add it to the PATH". If you are using windows i would do a search in the java jdk folder, it was in the bin folder  8 years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135699/where-is-jarsigner

Comment: I have installed the JDk and jarsigner.exe is present but I am getting this error. It says Add it to the PATH. But its already present. Which path should I use, Currently, it is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin

Comment: Did you add the folder to your windows PATH variables? If you just did it you should restart your PC and see if the error is still present

Comment: The project seems a bit outdated, because `jarsigner` is no longer used for signing APK files. Instead `apksigner` from Android SDK is used. You can try to upgrade the gradle project and android-gradle plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade the gradle project and android-gradle plugin.

Comment: Worked Like A Magic