# Android Studio 4.2.1 where is jarsigner now?

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio's embedded JDK (*C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre*) and I was using the `jarsigner` within it (*\jre\bin\jarsigner.exe*) to sign some bundles as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool).

When updating to Android Studio 4.2.1, I discovered that `jarsigner` is no longer in there. I don't really wish to install another JDK just for that, but I'm not sure there is another choice? did I miss something in the release notes informing us of this change or is there an alternative to signing bundles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is jarsigner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135699/where-is-jarsigner)

Comment: @mamen, no it does not. I know that if I install another jdk then I'll have it, I'm asking if there is another choice as it used to be in the embedded jre of android studio but has been removed for some reason. I'm wondering if this removal is due to a replacement tool or if it means that we'll have to use another JDK.

Comment: The answer to my linked question states that `jarsinger` is part of the **JDK**. You only have the **JRE** installed, that's why it is probably missing.

Comment: Thank you @mamen, I do know the difference between them and I did read that post before writing mine. I am referring to the fact that they recommend using the [bundled JDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk) (btw the **Gradle JDK** option in the link doesn't exist in the settings, the jdk is set in the project structure) but have removed `jarsigner` which presumably forces me to not use it anymore.