# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I have been looking at different post than we on the subject of error in error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES Eclipse, but I have not yet found the cause and how to fix it. I attached a screenshot of my Eclipse to see an idea that visual.

I have no idea how to fix this.

Sign the application for publication in google play, since then, I get this error, it can be? I can do? because if they lose the project ...

thank you very much!

[Capture my eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sdG1.png)

[image: Duplicated Android Manifest]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is INSTALL\_PARSE\_FAILED\_NO\_CERTIFICATES error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error)

Answer (score 6):

First [sign your apk with jarsigner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930331/how-to-sign-an-already-compiled-apk), then reinstall using `adb install -r <apkfile>` (or first uninstall the application that is signed with a proper certificate)

Answer (score 6):

For those with this problem...

**Select V1 (jar signature) instead of V2 (full apk signature)**

Selecting V2 could also cause this problem.[image]

Comment: where do i find this dialog?

Comment: Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK... > APK > (your key store) > Signature Versions

Answer (score 3):

if you got your old appication without the certificat on the device and try to install the new one with a certificat this will be a problem.

uninstall the old one and try it again.

For your next problem go to `eclipse.ini` and change the parameters from `-XmsAm` and `-XmxBm`.
Yours will be `-Xms40m` and `-Xmx384m` set them to `-Xms512m` and `-Xmx512m`

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. The problem is that I have not installed on the device. Neither in the emulator. I created a new emulator to test if that was the error and I have not gotten anything.

Comment: then this will help you :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/android-what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error

Comment: I will see what he says and test. Now I tell you, thanks for that I'm already desperate

Comment: Now this error : [2012-10-20 11:49:44 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;
[2012-10-20 11:49:44 - liverpoolguide] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;

Comment: Which jdk version you are using ? @Jorgechu

Comment: This is an ugly but fast solution: use JDK 6 instead of 7.

Comment: maybe you should restart eclipse after that changes

Comment: ok @Boe-Dev the second error it's OK. Now other error ¬¬ : [2012-10-20 12:03:09 - liverpoolguide] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml
Origin 1: C:\Users\jorgechu\Desktop\ANDROID\workspace\liverpoolguide\bin\resources.ap_
Origin 2: C:\Users\jorgechu\Desktop\ANDROID\workspace\liverpoolguide\bin\classes\AndroidManifest.xml   I've cleaned the project and I tried running again ...

Comment: you got more then one Manifest.xml, also your Buld Path looks crazy
my last idear is: right click on your project, go to android tools and use fix project properties, if that don't work you should start a new awnser here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18332/discussion-between-boe-dev-and-jorgechu)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and was able to fix it in this way:

1. uninstall the old application
2. clean the project
3. run and reinstall it again

Answer (score 1):

your **asserts , bin , res**  are not in valid format, delete those files and paste again in project, then **clean && build**   project again.. may it will give positive result

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time the solution for this error is really simple:
As i replied in: [What is INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/android-what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error/15925139#15925139)

> 1. Uninstall your apk.
> 2. Clean your android project.
> 3. Build your android project.
> 4. install / run your apk

Have fun