# Fixing debug.keystore to work with ADT 22 and Google Maps v1 API Key

Tags: android, keytool, google-maps-android-api-1

After updating my Android SDK to revision 22.0.1 and updating the Eclipse ADT, I found that I could no longer install a debug build on a device. The console shows this error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
```

I found that I could work around this by deleting my `debug.keystore` file and letting the SDK/ADT recreate it. This let me build and install a debug package.

However, the app uses the Google Maps v1 API, which requires an API key that is tied to the signature of `debug.keystore`.  Re-creation of `debug.keystore` invalidated that API key, and Google [is no longer providing new v1 API keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey). So when I run my debug build, the map view is blank.

This is not a showstopper, as a release build still works fine. But is there any way that I can "fix" my original `debug.keystore` such that it works with ADT 22 and matches my Maps v1 API key?

FWIW, here is the output of `keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android`:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Feb 20, 2012
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 4f427735
Valid from: Mon Feb 20 11:39:17 EST 2012 until: Sun Nov 16 11:39:17 EST 2014
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  C8:A5:4E:32:68:8A:50:90:C5:F5:A1:5B:3E:9A:CA:86
     SHA1: 0C:C4:5B:66:7F:54:C8:4D:2C:2D:D7:2E:9F:66:29:94:63:0A:19:7D
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
     Version: 3


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Comment: why dont you just move to v2 of maps and be done with it?

Comment: I'll move to v2 when the client is willing to pay for that work to be done. For now I just want to be able to run a debug build with working maps, like I could a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: I didn't have any problems when I upgraded to rev 22 and I have maps v1.  Have you tried looking for a solution to your original problem?  I found this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987150/install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error-in-eclipse)

Comment: Correction, I had problems (the common build path issue), just not with debug keys or the maps :)

Comment: Rebuilding the keystore is the only solution I've found. The old keystore worked fine before the ADT 22 update. After the update, using the old keystore always results in INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES, but using a new keystore works.

Comment: Did something else that chang on your environment (Java SDK ?)

Comment: @ddewaele: I don't think anything else changed, but wouldn't swear to it.  I don't care enough to try to roll everything back or reinstall everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but google map api 1 is no longer in use, you have need to use google map api v2 and only after this issue will get resolve.

Comment: Google Maps API v1 still works fine as long as you have a valid API key.

Comment: yes kristopher you are right Api v1 is still in use but in application development this api is deprecated by google.