# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android application I exported this application to send it to some people to test it I continue  the developpment of my  application and then when I tried  to  run it  with some  changement  I got this problem :

```
   Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
```

Can you help me !! to solve this problem !!

Comment: uninstall the old one and install it again.

Comment: You need to export it and sign it, not just export it. You can't install an apk which is not signed.

Comment: I uninstall the old one but I still have the same problem!!

Comment: I exported and I signed but now I can't run my modified app

Comment: @hayfa this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987150/install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error-in-eclipse