# After signing cannot run app in emulator due to INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I ran **Generate Signed Bundle/APK** to deploy a mobile app for internal testing. Now when I try to run the build in Android Studio on an emulator I get the following error:

```
05/03 08:08:31: Launching 'mobile' on Pixel 3 API 29.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/.../base-en.apk'
[1] '/Users/.../base-xxhdpi.apk'
[2] '/Users/.../base-master.apk'
APK signature verification failed.
```

I looked at these articles:

- [What is INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error) It's 10 years old and says to rebuild which I have tried. Does not seem related to the emulator.
- [Failure [install_parse_failed_no_certificates] when attempting to install APK to the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636396/failure-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-when-attempting-to-install-apk-to) but there was no accepted answer for it and the answers listed seemed somewhat dated.
- [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987150/install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error-in-eclipse) - 8 years old and with Eclipse

I expect this is a common workflow:

1. Deploy an app to internal testing
2. Make changes to app
3. Run multiple versions in emulator, including release, to see effect of new changes

It's when I run it against a released version in the emulator that I have problems, but this is somewhat essential to debugging a production issue if the issue is not happening in dev/staging.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have created additional buildType.  Each build type must have it's own `signingConfig`. The `debug` buildType has [preconfigured](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations) `signingConfig` for you.

So your options here are:

1. Create a new `signingConfig` as mentioned in the link
2. sign you internal testing app with the same debug signing config

```
android {

  buildTypes {
    internalTesting {
    ....
    ...
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I now I am encountering another issue. The app appears to be installed but when I click on it a tooltip appears "App isn't installed". To get around this I went to settings->apps->myapp->open and it opened from there.