# Android : ADB install error after signing the apk

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

I'm trying to install a signed apk to my emulator..The error I am getting is 
"***file abc.apk does not contain AndroidManifest.xml*** "...
I also, did zip the signed apk,to check AndroidManifest.xml....AndroidManifest.xml was available after unzipping the signed apk
Please help me with this...Unable to install signed apk on my emulator,so I guess I wont be able to upload it to Google Market :(

Comment: It's your own apk or downloaded from internet?

Comment: my own apk,i am trying to sign it manually...I signed an apk last month,it worked well...But now,its showing as AndroidManifest.xml missing...any idea abt the error ??

Comment: Try exporting apk using eclipse. apk signing is much easier using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I think I had two problems:

1. I was modifying the APK by renaming it to a .zip extension, extracting and then re-compressing, but on a Mac the folder structure doesn't persist correctly. Instead I used https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ to decode and then rebuild the APK.
2. You have to remember to re-sign your APK after modifying: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833908/62.