# cannot find zip-align when publishing app

Tags: android, zipalign

```
cannot.find.zip.align=The zipalign tool was not found in the SDK.

Please update to the latest SDK and re-export your application
or run zipalign manually.

Aligning applications allows Android to use application resources
more efficiently.
```

This is the message I received when I tried to publish my app. I'm using the latest revision of Android SDK Tools (23 which was released today) and SDK Platform-tools (20 which was also released today). I got an APK out of it, but if I tried to upload it to Google Play I got an error complaining that it is not zip aligned.

Running zipalign manually fixes the apk, but does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: The latest sdk tools(23) hasn't been packaged properly. Faced problems with many tools on this release.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
And to fix it, I copy the Zipalign file from sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W folder to sdk/tools/

**Edited:** Since Google updated SDK for Android, new build-tools does fix this problem. So I encouraged everyone to update to **Android SDK Build-tools 20** as suggested by Pang in the post below.

Comment: It must be a copy of the file and not a symbolic link in OSX. I used a sym-link (which is usually enough) and it was still not found.

Comment: I found it under - sdk\build-tools\20.0.0

Comment: Don't copy the exe from another directory. Use the SDK Manager to install SDK Build tools v20

Comment: When using ant build-release, one need to add sdk.buildtools=19.1.0 or =20.0.0 to project.properties.
Also note that zipalign properties set has been changed in the ANT build.xml to point on the righ tool chain version.

Comment: As mentioned in some of the answers that you need to install Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 20. I did. But still getting the same error. Then i have to copy Zipalign from "sdk/build-tools/20.0.0" to "sdk/tools/"

Comment: I downvoted this - the correct answer is to get the build tools version 20 (as in the answer given by Pang)

Comment: Now Zipalign tool is present at this location at /path/to/sdk/build-tools/zipalign.exe

Comment: Zipalign is deprecated as of Android Plugin for Gradle, Revision 2.2.0 (September 2016). See my answer below for details.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39708969/5309676

Answer (score 96):

I fixed it by installing Android SDK Build-tools 20:

In **Eclipse** → **Pull Down Menu** → **Window** → **Android SDK Manager**, check **Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 20**, then click the **Install *n* package(s)…** button to start installing.

Comment: I had to restart eclipse after doing this

Comment: Rev. 23.0.0 fix this issue... It's useful for latest build

Answer (score 20):

It becomes usable if you install

```
Android SDK Build-tools Rev.20
```

Answer (score 8):

I decided to just make a video for this..I kept pasting it into tools but alas that was not working for me. I moved it to platform-tools and voila publishing right away..must restart eclipse afterwards.

[Tutorial for fixing missing zipalign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nDGmPtRCsw&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Great video thanks, for me it worked by adding the zipalign to the tools and not platform tools

Comment: This link did help me, but instead of moving the zipalign.exe from the build-tools to the platform-tools, I just added the build-tools folder the PATH env

Answer (score 8):

I used the full path of zipalign. For mac, I found the executable file in Finder and clicked on it. Then, to publish my app I ran

```
/Users/username/development/sdk/tools/zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

instead of

```
zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

Comment: For windows (my zipalign path): `C:\Users\Machine\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign.exe`                                       My Example cmd `& 'C:\Users\Machine\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign.exe' -v 4 './platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk' './platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-signed.apk'`

Answer (score 8):

**Mac / Linux:**

This worked for me (you might want to replace **22.0.1** with version of your build tools):

Edit: ~/.bashrc

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk/
export ANDROID_TOOLS=~/Android/Sdk/tools/
export ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS=~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS
```

And run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or just close terminal and start it again.

Comment: just one edit: you missed the "export" in last line. :-)

Answer (score 7):

On a Mac, I did the following:

1. Find it on o/s (I had already downloaded build tools for 19 and 20)
2. Press Ctrl-Open to allow apps from the internet
3. Move it from sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W folder to sdk/tools/. Whew.

Answer (score 4):

With the SDK update to 20, version 20 of the build and platform tools and 23 of the sdk tolls, Google has moved a lot of things.

Gradle (if you are using Android Studio) however has not yet been updated to reflect those changes, as stated in other Answers copying the `zipalign` binary to `/sdk/tools/` should do the trick for now.

**UPDATE:** since Android Studio 0.8.1 got released the issue seems fixed now…
you only need to update your `build.gradle` and it should work fine again

`compileSdkVersion 20`

`buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"`

`targetSdkVersion 20`

and if you use any compat or support library

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'`

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'`

Comment: Point of clarification, move the binary from your android sdk folder to the android studio's sdk folder. Like:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign.exe
to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\zipalign.exe

Comment: google has updated android studio (0.8.1) and the issues do not occur anymore with this newer version

Answer (score 3):

Check in the SDK manager, that it has installed the "build-tools".  Mine in its default state, did not do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gradle just update ypur gradle plugin!

Change line in build.gradle from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
```

It works for me.

Note that variable buildToolsVersion (for me "20.0.0") must match your version of build-tools.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

With Android Studio 1.0 you have to use `zipAlignEnabled true`

Answer (score 1):

My fix worked copying zipalign.exe from **sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W** to **sdk\platform-tools**, as shown in video linked by digiboomz, and **did not work copying it in sdk\tools**

Answer (score 1):

If zipalign command is not found from Command-Line add file path of zipalign to environmental variables. As mentioned above, it's never good to change exe file location.

For Windows users:

Add to `User->PATH->"path to zipalign folder"`

In my case it path was `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W`.
In that folder is zipalign.exe

This link can help you with setting path and understanding it http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml#path

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse and this broke during an update. Here's what worked for me as the answers above did not.
I checked where ant's build.xml expected to find zipalign.exe.

In: `C:\Development\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml`
zipalign is defined as:

```
<property name="zipalign" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/zipalign${exe}" />
```

which indicates its expected in:

```
C:\Development\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\18.0.1
```

This directory corresponds to the highest version of the 'Android SDK Build-tools' displayed as installed in the 'Android SDK Manager'. So, that's where I copied zipalign.exe (which I obtained from an Android Studio installation!) and signed apps are now automatically zipaligned again!

Answer (score 1):

Steps to fix this,

1. Install  latest version of Android SDK Build-Tools
2. Check if zipalign.exe is available in folder android-sdk\build-tools\ e.g. android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.0\
3. In some older version of android you may not find zipalign.exe. Do not panic, check any other verion in which zipalign is available.
4. Open your project.properties file and configure build-tools to point to the  in which zipalign.exe is present. e.g. sdk.buildtools=21.1.0.
5. Restart your eclipse and try exporting again. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

i solved by RUN as Administrator @ your SDK Manager.exe in directory C:\Program Files\Android SDK

after that u'll get updated build tools an any repository

Answer (score 1):

On a mac with OSX 10.10.5,Android Studio and SDK installed the path is

```
/Users/mles/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign
```

Answer (score 1):

Zipalign gradle task is deprecated since Android Plugin for Gradle, Revision 2.2.0 (September 2016).

If you want to keep using it, add android.useOldPackaging=true to your gradle.properties file.

Click [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) for detailed explanation.

> Improves build performance by adopting a new default packaging pipeline which handles zipping, signing, and zipaligning in one task. You can revert to using the older packaging tools by adding android.useOldPackaging=true to your gradle.properties file. While using the new packaging tool, the zipalignDebug task is not available. However, you can create one yourself by calling the createZipAlignTask(String taskName, File inputFile, File outputFile) method.
>   APK signing now uses APK Signature Scheme v2 in addition to traditional JAR signing. All Android platforms accept the resulting APKs. Any modification to these APKs after signing invalidates their v2 signatures and prevents installation on a device. 
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

`zipalign` was moved to `build-tools\19.1.0` and `build-tools\20.0.0`, I assume you should use one of them in depend of your target SDK

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uninstalling Android SDK Platform (4.4W) and then reinstalling it.
I also restarted Eclipse after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case SDK Build Tools 20 were already installed.
I copied zipalign.exe in Tools folder but without success.

After that I noticed that I updated Eclipse without removing or renaming the old folder.

So I did:

1) Renamed old Eclipse folder
2) Restarted Eclipse

Eclipse asked to correct Android preferences because problem was Eclipse, that was still trying to use the old folder

Answer (score 0):

Normally the zipalign.exe is close of the "Android manager"(also, "Android", "Android SDK" etc), so you can ***search for "Android Manager"*** in windows search and give a ***righ-click*** above the command and ***open file location***.
You probably are in: something\ ***Android\android-sdk\tools***. Then is just necessary return a folder and go to ***Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3***.
The zipalign is there, you maybe be not able to use it with double-click, so you have to copy all the path of the ***zipalign*** file to use in ***CMD***, the final code that you have to input will be something like:

> C:\Users\heitor\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\zipalign.exe -v 4 android.apk android2.apk

Answer (score 0):

Google fix this mistake with the build tools version: 23.0.3
Now zipalign is packaged properly, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I was completely desperate, I did the following, that allowed me to find **official zipalign.exe**. The short answer is to use the link from official (but not public :-) part of of the site:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r28-rc1-windows.zip
```

If you use this recepy after 2018, you probably need the full explanation:

1. Open Android Studio and go

   ```
   Android Studio->Tools->Android->SDK Manager->Android SDK->SDK update site
   ```
2. Write in text editor link and open it in the browser. In my case the first link worked for me:

   ```
   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml
   ```
3. Look for the latest package build-tools. In my case, it was *build-tools_r28-rc1-windows.zip*, but you can find the latest in your time

   ```
   Ctrl+F build-tools_
   ```
4. Substitute in the URL the last part with the found package name like I did:

   ```
   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r28-rc1-windows.zip
   ```
5. Download the package, unzip it and fortunately find official file:

   ```
   zipalign.exe
   ```

If it helps you, your feedback is wellcome.

Comment: Android Studio->Tools->Android->SDK Manager->Android SDK ->SDK Tools -> check "Android  SDK Build-Tools 28-rc1"，then apply，you will install the build tools, and you can find zipalign.exe in SDK\build-tools\28.0.0-rc1 after installed.

Comment: You are right, It should be installed, but was not installed in my case. I checked. This recipe is for those who do not have this file after all attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue by doing this:

Open Android Studio > Preferences > SDK Tools and check "Android SDK Build-Tools"