# How to zipalign a signed android apk?

Tags: android

I am using android studio / Intellij Idea.

Each time I try to create the signed apk it says

> cannot.find.zip.align = The zipalign tools was not found.
>
> Please update the latest SDK and re-export your application or run
>   zipalign manually.

.[image]

then I updated my My SDK manager. Still it's giving me the same message. At this point I'm totally stuck.

**Need a proper solution to zipalign my APK.**

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24446579.

Answer (score 5):

Download sdk-Android4.4W. Just copy the Zipalign file from sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W folder to sdk/tools/

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to dowmload a new sdk. Simply copy the zipalign file from the latest buildtools directory to sdk/tools

So copy sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/zipalign to sdk/tools