# Unable to update APP on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

I had an application in Google Play for some time now. However I recently tried to update it with a new version. But when I tried to do so I get this error message:

> You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a
>   zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.

I think it is pretty obvious I have a *key store* and etc. so what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure that you have ***exported signed APK*** file. And for create zipalign package, follow this: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

Comment: Which IDE or tool you are using?

Comment: Android Tool -> Export Signed Application :) It is in the question how do you think I managed to upload it to the store at the first time?

Comment: Eclipse automatically generates Zipaligned Apk if you export signed APK. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442213/cannot-find-zip-align-when-publishing-app