# How to create a signed and unsigned working .apk using cordova?

Tags: cordova

## I am trying to create an .apk file for my mobile using cordova (Android) platform on ubuntu 14.04.

for unsigned i used command

```
$ cordova build --release android
```

or,
    $ cordova build android --release

it is creating an CordovaApp-release-unsigned.apk in ant-build folder
but while installing this the app gives error app not installed.

Note : i also want to build an release app using my name say xyz.apk.

```
# OS: Ubuntu 14.04
# Platform : Android
# Framework : cordova
```

Please help
post a best answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a keystock for signed apk

```
a.  keytool -genkey -v -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore -alias NAMEmobileapps -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
b.  create a file inside android folder using name "ant.properties"
c.  Add these line with your keystock full path and alise name.
    key.store=/home/chandradeo/xxx.keystore
    key.alias=xxx
```

Run command

```
$ cordova build android --release
```

or

```
$ cordova build --release android
```

This will give you both signed and unsigned apk under ant-build folder

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For you to be able to install the unsigned package in your device, you need to allow installation from unknown sources. It can be done in *Settings -> General (tab) -> Security* where you need to check the **Unknown sources** check box. After that the install should work.

If you want to sign your application to be deployable to for example *Play store*, you need to refer to [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) on that subject. you can also find steps for this from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930331/how-to-sign-an-already-compiled-apk). Once you have signed your .apk, you don't need to allow the unknown sources anymore.