# Crosswalk Google Play Store APK Sign

Tags: android, google-play, crosswalk-runtime, html-framework-7, crosswalk-project

I'm using **[framework7](http://framework7.io/)** for mobile app with **[crosswalk-project](https://crosswalk-project.org/)**.I want to add google play store my APK so how i can do that ? What I need to do to sign this APK ?

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sign an already compiled APK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930331/how-to-sign-an-already-compiled-apk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sign the APK, so I suggest you to read this in order to understand the process and make it easier: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

(Maybe "Signing Your App Manually" paragraph is the best shot for you).