# How To Sign APK files?

Tags: android

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000


jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

After I generate a certificate I need to run jarsigner in same CMD window?
Also do I have to move my .apk file to same folder were keytool is located or I can specify the path?

Please step by step me here?

Comment: I get access is denied?

Comment: why not sign with android studio itself? you don't have the project?

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24833908/1849543