# Is it possible to change signing of apk?

Tags: android

The client needs signed APK, but he does not gave us existing key. Meanwhile client also cannot create signed apk from code we gave him. The only options he ever consider: we gave him apk and he signed it with existing jks. however when he try to sign it with  the Jarsigner tools to re-sign the app with their Google Enterprise key, it is throwing an error:

```
unable to sign jar: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

There is something possibly wrong with GZIPInputStream or GZIPOutputStream, or possibly there is no gz.close(); which would need to be called on the GZIPOutputStream in order for the code to read it.v
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930331/how-to-sign-an-already-compiled-apk

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the app with different **.jks** file.
For more details read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist#marketupgrade)  also share with your client.