# Apksigner not signing apk on termux

Tags: android, super, termux

I'm compiling Mario 64 on termux on android, but I'm running into issues with it completing.

Here is the error that is occurring what do I have wrong?
Thanks!

```
apksigner sign --cert certificate.pem --key key.pk8 build/us_pc/sm64.us.f3dex2e.apk

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toPath()Ljava/nio/file/Path; in class Ljava/io/File; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.io.File' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)              
  at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:353)
  at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:83) make: *** [Makefile:887: build/us_pc/sm64.us.f3dex2e.apk] Error 1
```

```
$ ls -al build/us_pc/sm64.us.f3dex2e.apk
$ cp sm64.us.f3dex2e.apk storage/emulated/Download
cp: cannot stat 'sm64.us.f3dex2e.apk': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem yesterday. I managed to find a workaround by invoking `jarsigner` instead of `apksigner` (following `zipalign`), as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40064149/1110499

Answer (score 0):

I think its a basic issue of "File" and "file" ! Check the first letter in case it is accidently capitalized somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this [APK Signer](https://github.com/fornwall/apksigner)

And run `apksigner [-p password] keystore input-apk output-apk`
This will use the specified keystore (or creating one if necessary) to create the signed output file.