# Unable to sign apk with jarsigner

Tags: bash, cordova

```
@echo off
set spassw="password"
set kpassw="password"
cordova build android --release --keystore="developer.keystore" --storePassword=%spassw% --alias=developer --password=%kpassw% --prod 
del app-release-unsigned.apk
move e:\MobileJs\chatapp\ChatApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk e:\MobileJs\chatapp\ChatApp\
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore developer.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk developer

ERROR: jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format
```

I wrote a cordova build script and I cant seem to sign the APK
this is what my keystore generation looks like

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore developer.keystore -alias developer -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

```
Password: password
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]: First Last
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]: n/a
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]: n/a
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]: City
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]: State
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]: US
```

could it be the n/a

Answer (score 0):

you can refer here for keystore generation. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore) after generating keystore you can sign [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930331/how-to-sign-an-already-compiled-apk) your apk. After following these procedure if you are not able to generate feel free to ask.