# Update Android Native app to Flutter without uninstalling [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

Tags: android, flutter, android-keystore

I have an app on Google Play Store. I rewrote that app on Flutter but not published yet. I don't want users to lose their data on update. To solve this I want to write a conversion system but I need to be able to reach old database when Flutter app launches.

Android system doesn't allow two different app with same package name installed. When I try to install Flutter app on a device that has Native app, Visual Studio debugger gives `[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]` error. It uninstalls Native app and installs Flutter app so I won't be able to reach Native app's sqlite database.

Also the reason why I use the Google Play version is I lost my old project's latest update files. There is no fraud no worries :)

### What I tried:

- Make Flutter app's package name same as Native app's.
- Sign debug version with Native app's keystore file.
- Give Flutter app a higher version than Native app.

After steps I did above, first build stuck at `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...`. Output stays like this (I waited several times, maximum for 30 mins):

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
```

If I clean project, it builds in 30 seconds but uninstalls Native app with this output:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in projectname_2...
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/xxxxxx/projectname/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package ataberkw.projectname signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
Uninstalling old version...
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(11073): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:58745/lUE5l2_VlN4=/ws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that Google Play has it's own signature system additional to your keystore signing. Things may not exactly what I said but consequently apks Google Play and apks signed with your keystore doesn't have the same certificate. After this realization I came up with a solution.

1. Install the app from Google Play Store.
2. `adb adb shell pm path ataberkw.packagename` to get path of base.apk.
3. `./adb pull base-apk-path destination-path` to get base apk
4. Rename `base.apk` to `base.zip` and open it.
5. Delete `META-INF` folder inside `base.zip` and rename it to `base.apk` back. Now you have unsigned apk.
6. I used this [automatic apk signer](https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer) but you can use [manual ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40064149/4857232) too.
7. Reproduce the data at Native app and now you can install **signed** (use same jks file) Flutter app without need of uninstall.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your app's `applicationId`'s? If they are the same, that might make OS think that you are installing the same app again.
In Flutter, your `applicationId` is located in `android\app\build.gradle` file. You can address [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set_the_application_id) for documentation.

Comment: I already said package name is same. It means that I checked applicationId.

Comment: What I meant was that they have to be different than each other, not the same. But I am glad you found a solution.

Comment: Please read the question again. I don't want to delete the app so applicationId's already must be the same.