# Why does SHA-1 is not working in Google Play Console after reinstalling Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded one Android App in Google Play Console. After some days I updated as well. Now after I bought a new laptop, so I installed Android Studio. I run the signing report to get SHA-1, because I wanted to add SHA-1 in Google APIs. After that I release the APK with same old .jks and same credentials[password & key alias].

Now when I try to upload as a update in Google Play Console then I'm getting this:

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: E4:DC:C1:E9:E91..........:A0:EB:24 ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 46:BC:09:BE:12......3:A4:34:EF ]
```

**What I troubleshoot:**

- Clean Build
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Tried with App Bundle and App release signed APK Signature V1 and V2
- Upgraded versionCode and versionName everytime I tried to upload in Google Play Console.
- Had a research and tried to understand others answers who having a same problem.

But No luck! Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is the "same old .jks"? Use `keytool -list -v -keystore {path_to_keystore} -alias {alias_name}` to output its contents and SHA-1 specifically. You either sign APK with a correct keystore or with an incorrect keystore. There is no third option.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu path_to_keystore means .jks file path?

Comment: As my opinion this is not possible. I'm pretty sure you are not using the previous  key store. You must have to use the previous key store to update the app on playstore.

Comment: @SychiSingh, correct.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu is this correct? keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\abc\www.jks -alias key0

Comment: Should be correct if the path and alias are correct.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu searching for this: 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 I'm using win 10

Comment: Follow [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830283/7210237).

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Hey! I generated with that keytool command. Now what to do?

Comment: Use `keytool -list -v -keystore` command as aforementioned.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I read the comment but still I'm not getting what to do?

Comment: Use this command to print to the command line SHA1 of your `www.jks` keystore. And compare it with the error presented in the issue. Does it match the wrong SHA1 or the right SHA1?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu It is matching with this line in question: [ SHA1: 46:BC:09:BE:12......3:A4:34:EF ]

Comment: It's the wrong certificate. It should've been `E4:DC:C1:E9:E91..........:A0:EB:24`

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Any other possibilities? Like I might used  same .jks is used for other app which is now unpublished

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu for that Is there ay setting to change in google play console? same signing key/certificate something?

Comment: @SkSuraj Okay, I got to know that I lost the jks. Now I have doubts: If I'll contact support team, what will happen? Also, In console, is is possible that I remove published app and add new one? it's okay if I'll lose download. But I don't want to loose package name, because with that package name I created firebase project.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Okay, I got to know that I lost the jks. Now I have doubts: If I'll contact support team, what will happen? Also, In console, is is possible that I remove published app and add new one? it's okay if I'll lose download. But I don't want to loose package name, because with that package name I created firebase project.

Comment: @SychiSingh If you forgot the previous signing key don't worry. Now you can reset your signing key in play console. You just need to follow some steps. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613539/10844305

Comment: @SkSuraj I'm telling that I lost "same old.jks" file. Can I still able to do?

Comment: @SychiSingh Yes you can. You have to generate a new signing key. And tell play console support team to replace the old key with the new key. Then you can update your app on play store with the new signing key.

Comment: @SkSuraj Okay. thanks

Comment: @SkSuraj Can you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196982/how-can-i-get-exact-sub-category-name-about-a-place-from-google-places-api-in-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Following the discussion in comments*

Currently used certificate has next SHA1: `46:BC:09:BE:12......3:A4:34:EF`.

**It's the wrong certificate**. SHA1 should've been `E4:DC:C1:E9:E91..........:A0:EB:24`.

Make sure you use the old certificate with which you've signed your APK and uploaded **for the first time**. If the old certificate is lost and you cannot restore it **you will not be able to upload updates anymore**. Sad, but true.

*The next is not the fix of the issue but good to know*

[Opt in to app signing by Google Play](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll) to make Google Play store your certificate and handle signing. This way you have a much much lower chance of losing your certificate. And you will also be able to change the private key used for signing if it is lost or compromised. Huge improvement!

> If you lost your private upload key or your private key has been compromised, you can create a new one and contact the Google Play support team to reset the key.

Comment: Okay, I got to know that I lost the jks. Now I have doubts: If I'll contact support team, what will happen? Also, In console, is is possible that I remove published app and add new one? it's okay if I'll lose download. But I don't want to loose package name, because with that package name I created firebase project.

Comment: @SychiSingh, If you contact the support team they won't be able to help. You should be able to unpublish the application from the store BUT users who installed the app will be able to use it until they manually remove it and **you will not be able to completely remove the app from the Play Market**. And that means you will not be able to upload the same application with the same package name.

Comment: What is the solution then? Because that package name is associated with Firebase project

Comment: If the keystore is lost - create new keystore, create new Firebase project, change package name. No other solution is available in that case.

Comment: "DB in Firebase" - probably you can download it and upload to a new project. Not sure exactly as I've used it not so often.

Comment: Can you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196982/how-can-i-get-exact-sub-category-name-about-a-place-from-google-places-api-in-an

Comment: @SychiSingh Don't worry about your database. You can take backup easily from firebase. Export your db as json, and later import your db from json. That's it. And by the way, you don't need to actually create another firefase project. You can use the same for your app. You're not changing the package name. You're changing the signing key.