# How can I get exact sub category name about a place from Google Places API in Android/Java?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

See this screenshot:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpHX4.jpg)

If you'll carefully see the Image, for Fashion stop category is Men's clothing store and for Fabindia - Clothing store is written.

I also want this type of category name, but when I integrated API, I'm getting category name as

```
"types" : [ "point_of_interest", "clothing_store", "store", "establishment" ],
```

The problem is, I'm not getting exact name like Men's clothing store...

API used in Android App:

```
 data = makeCall("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + params[0] + "," + params[1] + "&radius=5000&type=" + params[2] + "&sensor=true&key=" + GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get place description from Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785672/how-to-get-place-description-from-google-places-api)

Comment: @DennisBauszus yes, I got that

Comment: @SychiSingh did you find the solution?

Comment: @SolaimanHossain this issue is official, and no hack is possible here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to get detailed place types/subcategories information from Google's Place API.

However, there is an open feature request in Google's Issue Tracker which I suggest starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future notifications:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822953

Comment: Can you help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64085441/which-credential-should-i-use-to-generate-token-followed-by-create-user-inside-k